# How to make a list(QList) of QFiles? and how it works?

Tags: c++, qt, qlist, qfile

I am trying to make a **list** of **QFiles**, I went for the **QList** approach but am not sure if it is good approach or not.
I write this code but it fails to build!

```
QList<QFile> filesList;

QFile file_1(QString("path/to/file_1"));
QFile file_2(QString("path/to/file_2"));

filesList.append(file_1);
filesList.append(file_2);

    for(auto& file : filesList){
        if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
            qDebug() << "file is not open.";
        }
}
```

The build failed with this error:

```
error: ‘QFile::QFile(const QFile&)’ is private within this context
     if (QTypeInfo<T>::isLarge || QTypeInfo<T>::isStatic) n->v = new T(t);
                                                                 ^~~~~~~~
```

Is it good to use **QList** approach of making a ***list of files*** to use later? if so, how to fix my code ?

Comment: tip: "best" puts your question closer to vague and opinions, which isnt necessary. When your code fails to compile then "best" is not relevant.

Comment: Usually we only need the paths. Use `QFile` only when you actually intend to open the file. It would be simpler to maintain a list of filenames instead of a list of `QFile`s.

Comment: It only exists in Qt 6. I'm going to remove my comment. If you read through all the compiler output you will notice that copying is intentionally turned off for `QFile`. Use a reference or smart pointer or - even better - store only the paths and create the file objects only when needed as @Fareanor suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that the QFile class has a private copy constructor, which means that it cannot be copied. Therefore, it cannot be stored in a container like QList. One way to work around this issue is to store pointers to QFile objects in the QList instead of the objects themselves.

Try this:

```
QList<QFile*> filesList;

QFile* file_1 = new QFile(QString("path/to/file_1"));
QFile* file_2 = new QFile(QString("path/to/file_2"));

filesList.append(file_1);
filesList.append(file_2);

for(auto file : filesList){
    if(!file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        qDebug() << "file is not open.";
    }
}
```

Updated version:

```
QList<QFile> filesList;

QFile file_1("path/to/file_1");
QFile file_2("path/to/file_2");

filesList.append(file_1);
filesList.append(file_2);

for(auto& file : filesList){
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        qDebug() << "file is not open.";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for dynamic allocation here. Why did you  not just append the addresses of the `QFile` objects (created on the stack) instead ? It would avoid the memory leak.

Comment: Where do the `QFile` objects get `delete`d? This leaks memory.

Comment: Or possibly `QList<std::unique_ptr<QFile>>` – this would get closer to the original attempt as not having to care for manual memory management. At best combined with `auto file_X = std::make_unique<QFile>(/*...*/)` and *moving* the pointer into the `QList` – support for at least *seems* to be provided considering an alias `rvalue_ref` existing.

Comment: @Friedrich you are right, there is no need for dynamic allocation and it would be better to use stack-allocated QFile objects instead of heap-allocated ones. I updated the post.

Comment: Updated version is identical to the OP.

Comment: @Fareanor This might be a consequence of producing the MRE, though, while the real code actually might indeed rely on dynamic allocation. Imagine a global list of files while the entries are created in within a separate function `openFile`...

Comment: The updated version is no different of the original one, and doesn't work for the same reason. You should store `QFile*` and append `&file_1` and `&file_2` into the list.

Comment: @Aconcagua QList<std::unique_ptr<T>> doesn't compile. Needs std::vector for move only objects

Comment: @Fareanor and once `file_1` goes out of scope you're left with a list of dangling pointers. Your original idea to store the paths was perfect. Why are people overcomplicating things?

Comment: @Aconcagua Maybe ! But if we don't know, we shall stay in line with the MRE in my humble opinion. If the file list is to be used right after, there is no need for dynamic allocation. Maybe it would be better to only keep the filenames in the list instead of `QFile` addresses, etc....

Comment: @Waqar Unfortunately. So apparently the `QList`'s implementation reflects pre-C++11 state of the art :(

Comment: @Friedrich Nope, not in the given code sample, because it's used in the same scope. If it wasn't, I would not have mentioned this at all (and in that case, dynamic allocation would be something to consider). But yes, in any case, I would suggest to only keep the filenames.

Comment: @Fareanor Again: *Maybe* – we do not know the use case, maybe it is undesirable having to open and close the file again and again. If that's the case I personally would go with a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<QFile>>` and if needing it for signals and slots possibly wrapping it (by value or by reference, depending on the use case) into a new `QObject` subclass specifically designed for this purpose...

Comment: @Aconcagua I completely agree with you ! But still, while things are only _"maybe"_ and not actual, and clear requirements, I find it too risky to assume anything. It's OP's responsibility to clarify his/her needs/use case. IMHO we should only compose with the information we have (that should not stop us from giving suggestions of course).

Comment: @Fareanor you are correct. I assumed the intention was to have central list of files to throw all around the application. I made an assumption which may have been incorrect. However, given the harm and surprise that may be caused I thought I'd better point it out.

Comment: Another possibility would be to load all the files once and for all and process their contents afterwards.

Comment: @Fareanor **Or** we provide variants for *both* alternatives like *'if you need the files only locally then `/*...*/` else you might try `/*...*/`'* – the code in the question is not explicitly packed into a single function so there always remains room for assumptions or interpretations – so even if relying on one single variant I'd consider necessary at least to leave a note about possible consequences like *'Note that if ... dangling pointers ...'*.

Comment: @Fareanor Well, actually all assumptions got obsolete anyway with accepted answer ;) However this whole matter might remain relevant for others stumbling over here and *not* wanting or being able to re-open files again and again...

Comment: @Aconcagua You're right, but sometimes, the combinatory of all possible solutions may be too big to be exhaustive (and often are not worth the effort since the question is probably about a specific use-case). But I agree, it would be the best ^^

Comment: Updated version's `filesList.append(file_1);` cause err use of deleted function ‘QFile::QFile(const QFile&)’

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Fareanor comment, I solved this by making a list of QString for the paths and I used QFile when I open the file:

```
QList<QString> filesList;

filesList.append("path/to/file_1");
filesList.append("path/to/file_2");

    for(auto& path : filesList){
        QFile file(path);
        if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
            qDebug() << "file is not open.";
        }
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, @Fareanor solved it. Give the guy some credit ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the QList of QFile, why not [emplacing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlist.html#emplaceBack) the elements?. No need for creating them outside and copying them in when they can be created in-place:

```
QList<QFile> filesList;

filesList.emplaceBack(QString("path/to/file_1"));
filesList.emplaceBack(QString("path/to/file_2"));

for(auto& file : filesList){
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        qDebug() << "file is not open.";
    }
}
```

Comment: For Qt 6.7 `filesList.emplaceBack(QString("path/to/file_1"));` cause err use of deleted function ‘QFile::QFile(const QFile&)